# JavaFX MediaPlayer drawing vertical lines on wide videos

Tags: java, video, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Using the JavaFX MediaPlayer for playing 1080p videos is no big issue. But I wanted to use 3K video (2880x1800) for my Retina display. For testing I used the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm) from oracle. Suddenly it drawed vertical line over the video and after the line the video had some kind of sepia filter. Example: [image: 2880x1800 video]

I also used an even wider video (5570x1080) and then a second line appears: [image: 5570x1080 video]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Log a [bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).  Include information in your report on the environment (OS/Java version/graphics card/graphics driver) and provide the developers access to a test video.

Comment: @jewelsea Just created a bug report. Please be so kind and vote it up: [Link](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39802)

Comment: Upvoted.  Try the [latest early access release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @JoLau I wanted to take a look at this issue but can't reproduce it - could you possibly update the link to the video in the ticket? (It gives a 404 at the moment.)

Comment: @berry120 Sorry, I don't have the video anymore. But you can either produce one by yourself or probably use the 4K version of Big Buck Bunny.